# Blackberry Curve 9300 and Bold 9650 - Support CSS Background Images in native Browser?

Tags: css, blackberry, mobile, background, background-image

I'm developing a website and a sizable portion of the viewers will be using the Blackberry Curve 9300 and Blackberry Bold 9650.

I've noticed that CSS background images are not displaying on these two devices.  It doesn't matter what element I apply a background image to (div, span, a).  I've never seen this behavior on any other mobile devices (I've only worked with iPhone and Android, so perhaps this is more common than I think?) - has anyone experienced this before?

Any ideas or relevant links to info is greatly appreciated!!
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any link that said "the css background images are not working for 9300 and 9650"; I created some of my application in blackberry webworks and blackberry I didn't get this type of problems;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am busy developing a wap site and I am having the same problem. On The blackberry site I found this link showing that only some versions support CSS background images.

[Blackberry CSS Support[1](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6153/Background-image_564460_11.jsp)

Hope this Helps